# Array_combine() with associative array

Tags: php

I've a problem with combine().
I've two arrays:

The first is called $divisions and it is like this:

```
    array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 5
      "name" => "Federico"
      "email" => "federico@email.com"
      "email_verified_at" => null
      "is_permission" => 2
      "created_at" => "2021-09-21T13:30:41.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2021-09-21T13:30:41.000000Z"
    ]
    1 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 7
      "name" => "Stefano"
      "email" => "stefano@email.com"
      "email_verified_at" => null
      "is_permission" => 2
      "created_at" => "2021-09-21T13:33:39.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2021-09-21T13:33:39.000000Z"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "name" => "Giada"
      "email" => "giada@email.com"
      "email_verified_at" => null
      "is_permission" => 2
      "created_at" => "2021-09-20T11:48:21.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2021-09-20T11:48:21.000000Z"
    ]
    1 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 4
      "name" => "Gianni"
      "email" => "gianni@email.com"
      "email_verified_at" => null
      "is_permission" => 2
      "created_at" => "2021-09-21T13:28:37.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2021-09-21T13:28:37.000000Z"
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "Michela"
      "email" => "michela.franchini@outlook.it"
      "email_verified_at" => null
      "is_permission" => 1
      "created_at" => "2021-09-20T11:47:36.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2021-09-20T11:47:36.000000Z"
    ]
    1 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 3
      "name" => "Roberto"
      "email" => "rob@gmail.com"
      "email_verified_at" => null
      "is_permission" => 2
      "created_at" => "2021-09-20T13:47:41.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2021-09-20T13:47:41.000000Z"
    ]
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▶]
]
```

The second is $shuffledRest:

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 10
    "name" => "Bool"
    "city" => "roma"
    "address" => "via del corso"
    "created_at" => "2021-09-21T13:04:54.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2021-09-21T13:04:54.000000Z"
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Da gianni"
    "city" => "Civitavecchia"
    "address" => "Via Benedetto Lucignani 1C"
    "created_at" => "2021-09-21T07:45:18.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2021-09-21T07:45:18.000000Z"
  ]
  2 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 8
    "name" => "Santa polenta"
    "city" => "Civitavecchia"
    "address" => "Via Benedetto Lucignani 1C"
    "created_at" => "2021-09-21T07:58:05.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2021-09-21T07:58:05.000000Z"
  ]
  3 => array:6 [▶]
  4 => array:6 [▶]
  5 => array:6 [▶]
  6 => array:6 [▶]
  7 => array:6 [▶]
  8 => array:6 [▶]
  9 => array:6 [▶]
]
```

So, now i try to combine this two arrays with array_combine() with this method:

```
$min = min(count($divisions), count($shuffledRest));
    $result = array_combine(array_slice($divisions, 0, $min), array_slice($shiffledRest, 0, $min));
```

I have to associate each item in $ shuffledRest with each item in $ divisions

It doesn't work and I've this message "Array to string conversion".

So, how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure `array_combine` is really what you want to use? It looks to me more like an `array_merge` kind of operation

Comment: I think `array_merge_recursive` could be what you ate looking for? Why is this question tagged Laravel. Your project might be Laravel, but this code is not Laravel-related

Comment: @GertB. i'ive edit the tags, sorry! I've seen array_merge_recursive but it's not what i'm looking for. I have to associate each item in $ shuffledRest with each item in $ divisions, so I thought using array_combine I would have no problem.

Comment: You need to give an example of what the result looks like.

Comment: _I have to associate each item in `$shuffledRest` with each item in `$divisions`_ Can you explain how you link the items in these 2 arrays

Comment: For example I need to associate restaurant "Da Gianni" with the first group of $divisions array

Comment: Why those 2 specifically? What is it that links them

Comment: @RiggsFolly Looks like `id`.

Comment: Hi @AbraCadaver Been caught out before making assumtions :)

Comment: @AbraCadaver Not sure what was ment by _with the first group of $divisions array_ either. As there are 2 different id's in that first ?grouping?

Comment: If you cannot add a little more detail to describe WHY items in the first array should be joined with items from the second array, then you run the danger of this question being ignored and eventually deleted

Comment: I have to make a lunch-roulette. the first array ($division) is formed by the various groups that will come out for lunch, the second by the restaurants ($shuffledRest).
I need to pair a group with a restaurant, to then be able to view them on the screen. The match is must be completly casual. Sorry for the late reply!!

Comment: So you want to place groups of people from the `$divisions` array into a random resturant from the `$shuffledRest` list of resturants

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes exactly!

Comment: This is starting to sound like a Homework Question, am I right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking for a bit of help with your homework. Beginners are welcome, but we expect a good faith attempt at an answer from you first. 
___SO is not a free coding service___ although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oh no, I don't want a free coding service. I simply didn't understand why I didn't get the desired result with the array_combine. I also tried with the merge and the merge_recursive but the tool that comes closest to what I need is the array_combine.

Comment: Can you do a `var_export()` on those 2 arrays, so I can test some code before posting it

Comment: I dont suppose it could be as simple as a typo in `$shiffledRest` in `array_slice($shiffledRest, 0, $min)`

Comment: And how do you want the resulting array to look